# django editable ListView

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have a model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    pub_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

I want to list all questions and edit them like inline forms.

I can list questions with ListView:

```
class UpdateDirectry(generic.ListView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'accounts/editable_directory.html'
    fields = ['question_text']
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
```

but this just list all questions.
I can also edit each question with UpdateView but I want all questions on a page to edit them.

Comment: One practice would be using AJAX. You can render each question using a form which has a submit button. Then you can submit the form to the URL supported with your `UpdateView`.

Comment: Thanks, I have a form for updating each question but I want them, to be like a spreadsheet (like Excel) and each field is like a cell. can you explain more about it?

Comment: You may find [this](https://realpython.com/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/) useful.